# Trying to make postgresql server available to another machine

Tags: postgresql

---

1. This is the error i'm getting while connecting to postgres server in server machine:

   ```
   Is the server running on host "192.168.0.109" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5433?
   ```
2. My version is 9.4 this question is answered so many times but nothing is useful to my problem.
3. I tried `Listening_address='*'` in `postgresql.conf`
4. Made changes to `pg_hba.conf`.
5. postgres.config.

---

This is `pg_hba.conf`:
[image: pg_hba.conf]

---

This is `pg.conf`:
[image: pg.conf]

Comment: Can you ping 192.168.0.109?

Comment: You asked if PostgreSQl server is accepting connections on port 543**3**. pg.config says `port = 5432`. Just a typo or do actually want it on 5433?

Comment: ya i'm able to ping 192.168.1.109

Comment: my server is on port 5432 and client is on same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just windows firewall issue.

1. Open control panel
2. Select System and security.
3. Select allow an app through windows firewall.
4. Then check postgres server if it is there or add it and check.
5. That's it........

   ### Thanks to everyone..........

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit `pg_hba.conf` to allow non-localhost connections. For example, if you want to allow client connections from any host on your local network (`192.168.*.*`) using md5 authentication you could add the following:

```
# Put your actual configuration here
# ----------------------------------
#
# If you want to allow non-local connections, you need to add more
# "host" records.  In that case you will also need to make PostgreSQL
# listen on a non-local interface via the listen_addresses
# configuration parameter, or via the -i or -h command line switches.

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all             192.168.0.0/16          md5
```

From the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html):

> An IP address range is specified using standard numeric notation for the range's starting address, then a slash (/) and a CIDR mask length. The mask length indicates the number of high-order bits of the client IP address that must match. Bits to the right of this should be zero in the given IP address. There must not be any white space between the IP address, the /, and the CIDR mask length.
>
> Typical examples of an IPv4 address range specified this way are 172.20.143.89/32 for a single host, or 172.20.143.0/24 for a small network, or 10.6.0.0/16 for a larger one. An IPv6 address range might look like ::1/128 for a single host (in this case the IPv6 loopback address) or fe80::7a31:c1ff:0000:0000/96 for a small network. 0.0.0.0/0 represents all IPv4 addresses, and ::0/0 represents all IPv6 addresses. To specify a single host, use a mask length of 32 for IPv4 or 128 for IPv6. In a network address, do not omit trailing zeroes.

Additionally, as @MyBrainHurts mentioned, make sure that your server is actually configured to listen on port 5433. The default port is 5432 as configured in `postgresql.conf`:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
          # comma-separated list of addresses;
          # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
          # (change requires restart)
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
```

Comment: Server doesn't listen
The server doesn't accept connections: the connection library reports 
could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060) Is the server running on host "192.168.1.206" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? 
If you encounter this message, please check if the server you're trying to contact is actually running PostgreSQL on the given port. Test if you have network connectivity from your client to the server host using ping or equivalent tools. Is your network / VPN / SSH tunnel / firewall configured correctly?

Comment: Have you restarted your postgresql server after altering postgresql.conf? If so, please post the latest settings related to ip addresses and ports you are using in pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf. You can limit the information to the same portions I provided in my answer.

Comment: up vote
0
down vote
unaccept
It's just windows firewall issue.

Open control panel
Select System and security.
Select allow an app through windows firewall.
Then check postgres server if it is there or add it and check.
That's it........
Thanks to everyone..........

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I got the solution.